# SQLServer pid kill

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to kill a `SQLServer` process id with a rollback process

Comment: Clarify, 'with a rollback' meaning you want to hard-abort the rollback? Or halt execution and begin rollback?

Comment: Do you want to check for running process?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

To find out current running process with:

```
USE DBNAME
EXEC sp_who2
GO
```

the And to kill process with id

```
Kill [process_id]
```